# Edit data from XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have the following XML file. I have managed to create a code that adds and removes data. However, I am not able or found anything helpful on how to edit the existing data. My goal is to let the user through a form to write the existing (let's say name) Ben and in another textbox the desired name and submit.
I am able to create the form and parse the two vars.
Thank you!

**the xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<messages>
    <message time="1248083538">
        <name>Ben</name>
        <email>Ben's Email</email>
        <msg>Bens message</msg>
    </message>
    <message time="1248083838">
        <name>John Smith</name>
        <email>john@smith.com</email>
        <msg>Can you do this for me?</msg>
    </message>
</messages>
```

Comment: what are you using to "add and remove data"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't "modify the XML" -- that implies that you're performing text-operations on it.  Possibly using some messy regular expressions and bunch of evil string-functions.  If you're not doing that, forgive me.

What you want to do is to:

- Read the XML and create a data structure.
- Operate on that data structure.
- Transform your modified data structure back into XML.

Lucky for you, [SimpleXML](http://us.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), makes doing exactly that nice and easy.