# Edit data from XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have the following XML file. I have managed to create a code that adds and removes data.
However, I am not able or found anything helpful on how to edit the existing data. My goal is to let the user through a form to write the existing (let's say name) Ben and in another textbox the desired name and submit.
I am able to create the form and parse the two vars. Thank you!

**the xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<messages>
    <message time="1248083538">
        <name>Ben</name>
        <email>Ben's Email</email>
        <msg>Bens message</msg>
    </message>
    <message time="1248083838">
        <name>John Smith</name>
        <email>john@smith.com</email>
        <msg>Can you do this for me?</msg>
    </message>
</messages>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Edit data from XML using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582183/edit-data-from-xml-using-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as simple as this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
foreach ($xml->message as $obj)
{
  $obj->name = 'new '.(string)$obj->name;
}
echo $xml->asXML(); /* output */
$xml->asXML($file); /* save into $file */
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the answer. The problem is that I can find a lot of codes and examples but I am not able to use it with what I need. Editing is difficult than adding or deleting

Comment: @user560411 - indeed, nobody going to know know what you need ... you might be look for [xpath query](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

Comment: The user will write in a form the value of a XML tag. For example Ben. In the other textbox of the form he will add what does he want Ben to be changed, for example Adam. Then the system will make the change and save the XML file.

Comment: @user560411 - in that case `$obj->name = $_POST['new_user_name'];` is good enough, you might need to escape the `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google, you can turn the XML file into an object and do whatever you want with it.
[link text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same as: [Add, update and edit an XML file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377632/add-update-and-edit-an-xml-file-with-php). Looks like the answer is there.

Comment: should have been a comment as it's only giving a possible duplicate

Comment: Ah, I don't know how to do that or at least I do not have the permission to do that.

Comment: True, [you need 50 reputation to comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) and [3000 to cast a closevote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions)